# Поля ввода, значения которых изменены с клавиатуры

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript, выборка

Здравствуйте. У меня есть много инпутов. Как выбрать все инпуты, текст в которых был изменен с клавиатуры (чтобы потом занести их в массив)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input').change(function(){$(this).addClass('user-changed');});
$('input.user-changed').each(function(){/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо повесить обработчик на изменение:

```
$(":input").change(function(){
  $(this).data("changed",true);    
});
```

Получаем массив измененных:

```
var changedInputs = $(":input").grep(function(input){
  return $(input).data("changed");
});
```

И не забыть при reset'е и submit'е (если submit идет ajax'ом) формы удалить флаги:

```
$(":input").each(function(){
  $(this).removeData("changed");    
});
```

Как-то так...

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать фиксировать ID инпута, если его изменяют. А проще выбрать все и каждый сравнивать с первоначальным значением (естественно первоначальное значение надо где-то зафиксировать, в БД или хотя бы в `input:hidden`).